# Are there any eslint rules that could prevent `Objects are not valid as a React child`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm writing React with Typescript and, after making a change to my code, I started seeing `Objects are not valid as a React child` errors.

I had changed a property from a `string` to an `Optional<string>`, so the error totally makes sense since my `<div>{property}</div>` code was no longer correct.

So, this is a type error being caught at runtime.

I'm not doing any casting or any other code "tricks" to try to subvert pre-existing type checking; I'm just rendering a value that React detects at runtime to be an object.

It seems to me that an appropriate linting rule or typescript configuration should have been able to capture that `property` is no a valid React child.

Here's a very simple example ([TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQoksiK62eMAIgPICycREuUocAtABMStOnRgBPMFjgAFYmHQBeOAG86cfXCwAPZOAA2WAFzaAvnRv06uCADtU8AGIQIcLQAptY1MwCxtLFTVUAEpfAD44AB5xYAA3WMCTcywbBIB6ZLSZdnweXgA6ShdxLCg-BK8fIKyNbQCbKJtc2IAaSVwAVxAsFxgygCMIcTkooA)):

```
type Props = {
    example:{}
};

const Foo = ({example}: Props) => <div>{example}</div>
```

I would expect an error pointing to the use of `example` inside the JSX.

I've been doing some googling, but I can't find a rule that seems like it would catch this.

Is there one that anyone knows of?

Comment: That is not an ESLint or TSLint error, that is an actual React error. https://github.com/facebook/react/search?q=Objects+are+not+valid+as+a+React+child . It means at some code path JSX is not being returned but rather an Object of some type, such as an error object perhaps from incomplete error handling, but hard to say without seeing the code. You are sure this is a compilation error rather than runtime error?

Comment: `You are sure this is a compilation error rather than runtime error?` @AlexanderStaroselsky I think their goal is to *add* a compilation error, so they can catch it before getting to the runtime react error.

Comment: I'm not sure I would expect a *linter* to capture that, but am surprised the *type system* doesn't. `<div>{property}</div>` gets transpiled to `React.createElement("div", null, property)`, and the `...children` rest args are typed as `React.ReactNode[]`.

Comment: Oh but that type is very wide, see discussion at e.g. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35622

Comment: Yes, this is currently a runtime error and I'd like for it to be a compile-time error. Personally, I think it should be a type-system error, but having read what jonrsharpe linked to, I can see why that would be hard. That's why I was hoping that there might be a configurable linting rule that would impose the restriction at build time that the renderer imposes at runtime... that's the whole point of the type system anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned there's no such a feature available right now. Furthermore linters are more geared towards styling than capturing compilation errors. I don't think what you're asking is possible because `example` is a dynamic type and setting it to a string makes it a valid JSX node while setting it to an object makes it invalid. Since JS is a dynamic language we cannot know this ahead of time. Typescript helps in this case, but that's a separate type system from eslint rules and as @jonrsharpe has mentioned in the comments there's an issue on typescript repository to add the feature you're requesting ([#35622](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35622)).